# C++ return value versus exception performance

Tags: c++, performance, exception

Somewhere I have read that modern Intel processors have low-level hardware for implementing exceptions and most compilers take advantage of it, to the effect that exceptions become faster than returning results state using variables.

Is it true? are exceptions faster than variables as far as returning state/responding to state?  reading stack overflow on the topic seems to contradict that.

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know where you read this, but it is surely incorrect. No hardware designer would make exceptional circumstances, which are by definition uncommon, work FASTER than normal ones. Also keep in mind that C, which according to [TIOBE](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html) is the most popular systems language, does not even support exceptions. It seems EXTREMELY unlikely that processors are optimized for ONE language's exception handling, whose implementation is not even standardized among compilers.

Even if, somehow, exceptions were faster, you still should not use them outside their intended purpose, lest you confuse every other programmer in the world.

Answer (score 14):

Be aware that there's ambiguity in the term "exception handler." I believe you'll find that hardware folks when talking about exceptions mean things like:

1. Hardware interrupts, aka signals, whose handlers are sometimes called exception handlers (see http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~smoler/x86text/lect.notes/interrupts.html)
2. Machine check exceptions, which halt the computer if something in hardware goes wrong (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_Check_Exception)

Neither of those has anything to do with C++'s exception handling facility.

As a counterexample, I have at least one anecdotal data point where exceptions were way slower than return codes: that was on Intel hardware alright, but with gcc 2.95 and a very large set of code with a very large exception table, that was constructed the first time an exception was thrown. Subsequent exceptions were fast, but by then the damage was usually done. Admittedly, gcc 2.95 is pretty ancient, but it should be enough to caution you about making generalizations about the speed of C++ exception handling, even on Intel hardware.

Answer (score 4):

No. Nothing is going to be faster than sticking a variable into a register. Even with explicit hardware support, exceptions are still going to require things like memory accesses.

C++ exceptions couldn't be implemented for the most part in that way, because c++ requires that the stack be unwound and objects destructed.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is technically correct, but *highly* misleading.

At the core of the issue is the observation that exceptions are exceptional. They usually do not happen. This is not the case when you return an error code. This happens always, even if there is no error. In that case the function still has to return `0`, or `true`, or `-1`, or ...

Now this means that a CPU and a compiler can specifically optimize functions that fail by exception. But it's important to realize *what* they optimize, and that's the non-failure, non-exception case - at the cost of the exceptional cases.

Once we realize that, we can look at how the compiler and CPU optimzie such cases. One common method is putting the exception code separate from the normal code. As a result, that code will normally not end up in the CPU cache, which can contain more useful code as a result. In fact, the exception code might not end up in RAM at all, and stay on disk.

Another supporting mechanism is the CPU branch predictor. It will remember that the branches that lead to exception code are usually not taken, and therefore predict that the next time they're not taken either. The compiler can even put this in as a hint. However, this hint feature was abandoned past the Intel Pentium 4; modern CPUs predicted branches well enough.

Answer (score 0):

Even if they were faster, you should not use them for anything other than exceptional conditions.  If you misuse them you make your program much harder to debug.  In gdb you can do a 'catch throw' and easily find out where your program is going wrong and throwing an exception, but not if you're throwing exceptions as part of your regular processing.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, because what you mean by *implementing* exceptions covers three things:

- Entering a `try` block. This *can* have *no* cost, but tends to make a `throw` more expensive. There is [a more specific question about this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897940/in-what-ways-do-c-exceptions-slow-down-code-when-there-are-no-exceptions-thown).
- Executing a `throw`. There is [a more specific question about this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018800/cost-of-throwing-c0x-exceptions).
- Unwinding the stack to get from a `throw` to its `catch`, and loading the error handling code (in the `catch`) into the CPU cache. Your should ignore this cost, because you must pay this cost if using status codes rather than exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is blog article where someone did some actual benchmarks: https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2020/performance-overhead-of-exceptions-in-cpp/

tl;dr: The `throw`/`catch` mechanism is about an order of magnitude slower than returning a value, so if you care about performance you should only use it in exceptional situations.